# Hash and array: a compromise between performance and utility\maneuverability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json, hash

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to handle properly web service responses finding a compromise between performance and utility\maneuverability.

I have to decide what type of response my web service must return back to the web client application. I am using JSON for trasmitting data and I would know if it is better to use *hashes* (for these I have to do extra work) or *arrays*.

For example I have this response:

```
[
  {
    "accounts" => {
      [
        "account" => {
          "id"   => 45, 
          "name" => "Test_name45", 
          "..."  => ..."
        }
        "account" => {
          "id"   => 60, 
          "name" => "Test_name60", 
          "..."  => ..."
        }
       ]
     }
   }, 
   {
     "other"  => {
       "sub_other" => {...}
     }
   }
]
```

I would like to use something like (no array in "accounts", from "account" to "id")

```
  {
    "accounts" => {
      "45" => { 
        "name" => "Test_name45", 
        "..."  => ..."
      }
      "60" => {
        "name" => "Test_name60", 
        "..."  => ..."
      }
   }, 
   {
     "other"  => {
       "sub_other" => {...}
     }
   }
```

but the latter means more work for the web service...

**How to make that? Any advice?**

Comment: In the current form I think that's more or less undecidable. Any more info on what kind of webservice?

Comment: @Jakub Hampl I updated the question.

Comment: My rule of thumb is hashes are used when you want random access to data, and arrays are for when you want sequential access. There are times you mix and match, and others when you can stick with one or the other. Only you can determine that based on the data you want to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use whichever data structure makes sense. If you have a *list of things* then use an array where each element is a *thing*. I would probably simplify your data structure to something like this:

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "id":   45, 
      "name": "Test_name45", 
      "...":  "..."
    },
    {
      "id":   60, 
      "name": "Test_name60", 
      "...":  "..."
    }
  ],
  "other": {
    "sub_other": {"...": "..."}
  }
}
```

Now, `accounts` is just an array of objects--no need to go looking things up by key. In Ruby this translates nicely:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > data = JSON.parse(json)
 => {"accounts"=>[{"id"=>45, "name"=>"Test_name45", "..."=>"..."}, {"id"=>60, "name"=>"Test_name60", "..."=>"..."}], "other"=>{"sub_other"=>{"..."=>"..."}}}
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > data["accounts"].each { |acct| puts acct["name"] }
Test_name45
Test_name60
 => [{"id"=>45, "name"=>"Test_name45", "..."=>"..."}, {"id"=>60, "name"=>"Test_name60", "..."=>"..."}]
```